# How to prevent "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression" in jQuery tablesorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, syntax, tablesorter

I use the automatical identification of column data types of jQuery tablesorter. In one of my columns I have some voltage ranges, such as "±10 V". This seems to disturb either tablesorter or whatever:

uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ±10 V

I'm not sure even how to debug this problem. Does anybody have an idea? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, the relevant HTML is:    <td class="foo">±10&nbsp;V</td>   Without the ±, the error is gone, but that's not a solution :~)

Comment: The sorter probably doesn't understand the special character ±.

Comment: Probably not. But what is the fix?

Comment: Can you get away with having the ± in the column header as general rule for the data in that column to save yourself some trouble?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the `±` is not applicable to all rows. But this brings me to just use `+/-` instead of `+-`. Not as beautiful, but it should work.

Comment: But, no, it doesn't. The string must start with an alphanum to prevent the exception.

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is the **±** then use the **`&plusmn;`** HTML escape

reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Neither `&plusmn;` nor `&#177;` do change anything. I assume the web browser already replaces these codes with `±` or whatever. That way tablesorter or whatever doesn't like `±` sees this symbol in any case.

Comment: than you enter a different expression that expected, you should give a http://jsfiddle.net demo to let us help you.

Comment: That's an interesting tool. I'll need some time to work this out, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `&#177;` instead of ±

can also add this jquery code to your value that will do it automaticaly

```
var result = oldValue.replace('±', '&#177;');
```

EDIT: since you say previous solution doesn't work, have you tryed this? just force string type. might work.

```
value.toString()
```